# No method navigate(String) in compose-navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying the new jetpack library "**compose-navigation**".

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable), to navigate to a route, I should use `navigate()` method which takes a **String**.

```kotlin
navController = rememberNavController()

// navigate
navController.navigate("/another_route")
```

However, **no such method exists** `navigate(String)` and I get compile error.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`navigate(String)` is not part of `NavController` class, but an **extension function**

To solve the error, "*import the function route in the file*":

```kotlin
import androidx.navigation.compose.navigate

// and then navigate
navController.navigate("/another_route")
```

And it'll work fine.

Unfortunately, you don't get the completion that you expect.